# Syntax error in Visual Force page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a problem in the below code:

```
<apex:column value="{!(CASE((item.dayOfWeek__c), 1, 'Monday', 2, 'Tuesday','Friday'))}" />
```

This code is giving me the error:

```
Syntax error. Missing ')'

Error is in expression '{!(CASE((item}' in component <apex:pageBlockTable> in page addimr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
 <apex:column value="{!CASE(item.dayOfWeek__c, 1, 'Monday', 2,
    'Tuesday','Friday')}" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it is still not working. Syntax error. Missing ')' Error is in expression '{!CASE(item}' in component <apex:pageBlockTable> in page addimr ..

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not in 2020. 
For some reason VF's logic functions cannot be used to populate the values of apex:column tags.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled into this same dumb error myself.  The solution is to display the value in an `<apex:outputText>` contained within the `<apex:column>` tag, as outlined in this solution:

[Syntax error. Missing ')' -only occurs in Apex:column](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i18VAAQ)

```
<apex:column>
  <apex:outputText value="{!LEFT( r.Contact__c,1) } "></apex:outputText>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: This worked for me and should be the accepted answer.
Apparently apex:column "value" cannot be populated using functions.